# How do i make one form for two related models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms, form-for

I want to write data for 2 different models that are related to each other like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :roads
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :roads, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Road < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Of course de roads table has a "post_id column". My form_for in the post view looks like this

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Tu_Nombre %>
    <%= f.text_field :creador, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :año %> (Cuando fue tu experiencia?)
    <%= f.text_field :año, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= fields_for :roads do |r| %>
      <%= r.label :principio %> (desde?)
      <%= r.text_field :principio, class: "form-control" %>

      <%= r.label :final %> (hasta?)
      <%= r.text_field :final, class: "form-control" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :historia %> (Cuentanos la historia de tu viaje!)
    <%= f.text_area :historia, class: "form-control", size: "50x15" %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Finally my posts_controller create method

```
def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' 
  else
    render :new 
  end
end
```

with the private

```
 def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:historia, roads_attributes:  [:pricipio, :final, :post_id])
 end
```

The post is submitted and if i check the console all the atributes for post has been saved but the ones for road, has not. How can i use just one form two make records for these two models and that the post_id gets registered so i can relate the tables?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your posts_controller `new` method to include `.build`

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.roads.build
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Nested Forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) in Form Helpers chapter of Rails Guide. You could use `fields_for` to build the nested attributes form for your `roads` and permit nested attributes like the example. Below is an example from rails guide, you could try and figure it out yourself.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  Addresses:
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |addresses_form| %>
      <li>
        <%= addresses_form.label :kind %>
        <%= addresses_form.text_field :kind %>

        <%= addresses_form.label :street %>
        <%= addresses_form.text_field :street %>
        ...
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

permit nested attributes in people_controller.rb

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, addresses_attributes: [:id, :kind, :street])
end
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, there was the solution, i was missing the @post.roads.build in the posts_controller

Answer (score 0):

Attach your fields_for to the parent form builder like so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :roads do |r| %>
```